# How to manipulate directory paths to work across multiple OS?

Tags: python, python-2.6

I'm writing a python script which has to internally  create output path from the input path. However, I am facing issues to create the path which I can use irrespective of OS.

I have tried to use os.path.join and it has its own limitations.
Apart from that, I think simple string concatenation is not the way to go.
Pathlib can be an option but I am not allowed to use it.

```py
import os
inputpath = "C:\projects\django\hereisinput"

lastSlash = left.rfind("\\")

# This won't work as os path join stops at a slash
outputDir = os.path.join(left[:lastSlash], "\internal\morelevel\outputpath")

OR

OutDir = left[:lastSlash] + "\internal\morelevel\outputpath"
```

Expected output path :
C:\projects\django\internal\morelevel\outputpath

Also, the above code doesn't do it OS Specific where in Linux, the slash will be different.

Is os.sep() some option ?

Comment: you can use: import os

Comment: Use raw strings when string value contains OSpath,  otherwise unicode decode error may arise

Comment: You shouldn't use a partially completed path with `os.path` because that part won't be fixed. It only joins parameters it doesn't fix them: `os.path.join('start', 'internal', 'morelevel', 'outputpath')`

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation `os.path.join` can join "**one or more** path components...". So you could split `"\internal\morelevel\outputpath"` up into each of its components and pass all of them to your `os.path.join` function instead. That way you don't need to "hard-code" the separator between the path components. For example:

```
paths = ("internal", "morelevel", "outputpath")
outputDir = os.path.join(left[:lastSlash], *paths)
```

Remember that the backslash (`\`) is a special character in Python so your strings containing singular backslashes wouldn't work as you expect them to! You need to escape them with another `\` in front.

This part of your code `lastSlash = left.rfind("\\")` might also not work on any operating system. You could rather use something like [`os.path.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.split) to get the last part of the path that you need. For example, `_, lastSlash = os.path.split(left)`.

Comment: yup, Thanks.
Seems one good option.

I thought python might have some standard ways to cater such issues for paths.
Becuase finally, it is creating a full path by appending x to y where both x and y contain separators.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your original path is "C:\projects\django\hereisinput", your other part of the path as "internal\morelevel\outputpath" (notice this is a relative path, not absolute), you could always move your primary back one folder (or more) and then append the second part. Do note that your first path needs to contain only folders and can be absolute or relative, while your second path must always be relative for this hack to work

```
path_1 = r"C:\projects\django\hereisinput"
path_2 = r"internal\morelevel\outputpath"
path_1_one_folder_down = os.path.join(path_1, os.path.pardir)
final_path = os.path.join(path_1_one_folder_down, path_2)
'C:\\projects\\django\\hereisinput\\..\\internal\\morelevel\\outputpath'
```